# Use of dyanmic ID in xpath - Python(Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of ID and want to pass these IDs in XPath dynamically. Below is the code I am using:

```
hd_DescText=''
for HD_IdValue in CT_3_row_IDs:
    path=".//tr[@id='" + HD_IdValue + "']/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/font"
    path=str(path)
    print(path)
    hd_DescText=browser.find_element_by_xpath(path).get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print(hd_DescText)
    #contains(@id,'"+ HD_IdValue + "')
```

Though print(path) is giving the exact path while executing this code. I am getting the below error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":".//tr[contains(@id,'tr_m_1570_1025516')]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/font"}

Comment: Did you add a wait? Did you check to see if your desired element is inside an `IFRAME`? Did you verify that the XPath actually locates the element using the browser dev tools? We can't really answer this without a link to the page or more information.

Comment: Where I have to add the wait? The desired element is not in the IFRAME. XPath is locating the element using the browser dev tools.

Comment: You would add a wait to your find. It's generally a good idea to add a wait before touching anything on the page in cases where it loads slower than usual or is not immediately available. See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I am able to pull the required data, after using the below line of code:

```
path="//*[@id=" + "'"+ HD_IdValue + "'"+ "]/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/font"
hd_DescText=browser.find_element_by_xpath(path).get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Here **HD_IdValue** has dynamic values of IDs.